# Python: Help needed with converting percentage to gpa

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program where it would convert the percentage to grade point value.. and I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to code it.

This is what I thought of it as:

```
def percentage_function(x):
    if (percentage_function < 90):
        return 4.0
```

Not too sure how to begin since I'm a beginner in python..

Comment: Look at the python docs tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/

Comment: but would i use lists to start it or make them in a if statement?

Comment: Both would work, the beauty in programming is that there are many ways to solve a problem. Try one approach and see if that works

Comment: so what I tried coding above wouldn't work at all?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the function to a number, where you want to compare the parameter to the number. It should be:

```
if (x < 90):
    return 4.0
```